# Why can't I set a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

Why won't this work? I've tried both localhost and an actual server:

```
<?php
setcookie("name", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
echo $_COOKIE["name"];
?>
```

Unlike in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347443/php-array-from-cookie-info-only-shows-up-after-you-refresh-the-page), it doesn't show up on refresh.

Answer (score 1):

[setcookies](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setcookie.php) does *not* affect the $_COOKIE array in the current request; it only informs PHP to add a cookie response header, while $_COOKIE contains the cookies sent by the client.

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers ..
>
> .. [set cookies] can be accessed on the *next* page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays ..

Comment: That's what I thought, but the cookie isn't found on reload either.

Comment: @GoldenJoe Inspect the request sent to the server (via the Browser Developer Tools / Network Monitor) to find out what happens: it should result in a cookie  header (from the server) and then a subsequent cookie header (to the server). The lack of one (or the other header) will indicate why the cookie is not being persisted. Include relevant information discovered in the original question.